# How to execute a function only after completion of previous functions in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have tried to execute 4 function in a row inside dojo domready block and also i want to set a Boolean flag after the execution of these functions, but all function are fired in order asynchronously and the flag is set before the completion of these function i.e. the functions doesn't wait for the previous function to complete, they all are just started and move to the next one.

```
    require([ 'dojo/domReady!' ], function() {
        boolean flag=false;
        function1();
        function2();
        function3();
        function4();
        flag=true;
    });
```

How to set the flag only after the execution of all the 4 functions

I am sharing my original code, first i am executing the initial call in dojo ready, where i am setting the flag onload to false first

```
require([ 'dojo/domReady!' ], function() {
    onload = false;
    getQuoteOption();
});
```

then in the function 'getQuoteOption()' i am firing an ajax call to get fetch some json data

```
    function getQuoteOption(){
        var reqParams = addQuoteReqParams(reqParams);//getting json input data
        var request = require("dojo/request");
        request.get(url, {
            query : {
                inputJson : reqParams
            },
            handleAs : "json",
            preventCache : true
        }).then(function(response) {
            configureQuoteFieldData(response);
            configureIrregularFrequencyData(response);
            onload=true;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

in the callback of the ajax call i am executing two functions 'configureQuoteFieldData(response)' and 'configureIrregularFrequencyData(response)' and then setting the flag onload to true believing the two former functions have executed completely but the flag onload is set to true before that.

for referring i am listing two function also here

```
 function configureQuoteFieldData(quoteFieldData) {
  var registry = require("dijit/registry");
  registry.byId('form_quoteData').set('value', quoteFieldData);//setting data to form 
 }



 function configureIrregularFrequencyData(obj) {
    var tmpArray = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
            tmpArray.push(obj[i]);
        }
        irregularPayMonths['irregularData'] = tmpArray;//saving to global variable

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your functions to accept a callback or return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Then trigger the subsequent function with that instead of just calling it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

With the code snippet shared, the flag will be set after executing all the 4 functions. But, that does not mean that it has completed executing all the logic within those function. If there are some asynchronous calls within those functions then they will be executed after the flag is set.

If you could share the code within those functions, then we could give more specific solution.

UPDATE:
I believe the code for getting the registry, may be causing the problem.

```
var registry = require("dijit/registry");
```

The require gets the js file if it is not already retrieved from the server. that might be what is happening in your case. Try to have only one single require per script file. that way all the required files are retrieved before execution.

```
require(["dijit/registry","dojo/request", "dojo/domReady!"], function(registry, request) {

    function getQuoteOption(){
        var reqParams = addQuoteReqParams(reqParams);//getting json input data
        request.get(url, {
            query : {
                inputJson : reqParams
            },
            handleAs : "json",
            preventCache : true
        }).then(function(response) {
            configureQuoteFieldData(response);
            configureIrregularFrequencyData(response);
            onload=true;
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    function configureQuoteFieldData(quoteFieldData) {
        registry.byId('form_quoteData').set('value', quoteFieldData);//setting data to form 
    }

    function configureIrregularFrequencyData(obj) {
        var tmpArray = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
            tmpArray.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    onload = false;
    getQuoteOption();
});
```

Make sure the order of module and corresponding function parameters are matching.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `dojo/promise/all` and `dojo/Deferred`, the idea is to use deferred objects as mentioned by @Quentin.

Below a live example using specifically dojo framwork.

https://jsfiddle.net/9khdr4qa/

Explanation:

- The code runs 3 functions which will return asynchronously, each function return at a different time as indicated by setTimeout().
- Now you wish to set your flag to true, only after all 3 functions are returned and done.
- The solution include a deferred object in each function. When the function return the deferred object is `Fulfilled`.
- Use `dojo/promise/all` to detect when all 3 functions are returned. Basically its callback will run only after all 3 deferred objects are marked as `Fulfilled`.
- Than set you `flag` to `true` and carry on with your code.

You can read more about dojo promises and deferred object here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise.html

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/Deferred.html

```
require(["dojo/promise/all", "dojo/Deferred", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/json", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(all, Deferred, dom, on, JSON) {
    var flag = false;

    function requestA() {
      var deferred = new Deferred();
      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("requestA");
      }, 500);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function requestB() {
      var deferred = new Deferred();
      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("requestB");
      }, 750);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function requestC() {
      var deferred = new Deferred();
      setTimeout(function() {
        deferred.resolve("requestC");
      }, 1000);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    on(dom.byId("startButton"), "click", function() {
      dom.byId("output").innerHTML = "Running...";
      all([requestA(), requestB(), requestC()]).then(function(results) {
        dom.byId("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(results);
        flag = true;
        alert('Your flag is set to: ' + flag);
      });
    });

  });
```

---

```
<h1>Click to start:</h1>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<button type="button" id="startButton">Start</button>
```